# django multiple ModelForms with the same model and ForeignKeys

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am building a simple question-answer app with Django.  My simplified model is:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.TextField('Question', max_length=256)

class AnswerChoice(models.Model):
    choice_text = models.CharField('Choice', max_length=32)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    is_correct = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I have two `ModelForm`s for the two models above (`QuestionForm` and `AnswerChoiceForm`).

Now, I show a `QuestionForm` and 4 `AnswerChoiceForm`s on a HTML page for editing a question and adding 4 answer choices for the question.  I want to make sure that the user marks exactly one answer as "correct".

My view function is:

```
def edit_question(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        question_form = QuestionForm(request.POST)
        choice_forms = [AnswerChoiceForm(request.POST, prefix=str(i))
                        for i in xrange(4)]
        if all(c.is_valid() for c in choice_forms) and question_form.is_valid():
            choices = [c.save(commit=False) for c in choice_forms]
            question = question_form.save()
            for c in choices:
                c.question = question
                c.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(...) # show the question just added
     # ...
```

Now, I want to verify that *exactly one* of the choices out of the 4 is marked correct.  I could do this check in the `edit_question` view function above, but somehow that seems a bit "wrong": I am adding core logic to a view function which I am not completely happy with.

Is there a way to do this verification either in my `Question` or `AnswerChoice` models, or in the definition of the model forms?

I have not provided a complete minimal code above in the hope that the amount of code shown is enough and that it doesn't get too long.  If you need to see more code, please ask and I will edit this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you are not using a formset for the answer forms. You should: not only are they less clumsy than instantiating four forms separately, they have a `clean()` method that is specifically meant for validation that goes across the child forms, rather than being per form. Something like this:

```
class AnswerFormSet(forms.models.BaseInlineFormSet):
     def clean(self):
        correct_count = sum([form.cleaned_data['is_correct'] for form in self.forms])
        if correct_count != 1:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Exactly one answer must be marked as correct')
```

And in the view you would do this:

```
def edit_question(request):
    AnswerFormset = forms.models.inlineformset_factory(
         Question, Answer, formset=AnswerFormSet, extra=4, max_num=4)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        question = Question()
        question_form = QuestionForm(request.POST, instance=question)
        answer_formset = AnswerFormset(request.POST, instance=question)
        # Check these separately to avoid short-circuiting
        question_valid = question_form.is_valid()
        answer_valid = answer_formset.is_valid()
        if question_valid and answer_valid:
            question_form.save()
            # No need to add new question as it was already set as the instance above
            answer_formset.save()
        # etc
```

Comment: Thank you.  This is exactly what I needed, and it's much cleaner.  I am assuming `return self.cleaned_data` is a typo in the `clean()` method of `AnswerFormSet`?  (Django complains about no such attribute.)

Comment: Ah yes, you don't need that line, deleted.

Answer (score 0):

One option is as under:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.TextField('Question', max_length=256)
    def validate_answers(obj):
     if obj.answerchoice_set.filter(is_correct=True).count()==1
       #All well
       return True
     else:
       #delete question and answers if you wish or request for change
       return False
```

But you should keep in mind that this will check if your answers are valid after everything is saved. And then if you want you may delete your questions or answers.

```
def edit_question(request):
  #your usual code
  return (HttpResponseRedirect(...) if question.validate_answers() else  HttpResponseRedirect(...))
```

Comment: This works, but one thing I wanted to avoid was to save my model instance to the database in case of errors.  Thanks for the answer!